# How to use a class abc as object in a datastructure say "List"?

Tags: c#

```
public class abc
    {
        public static void main()
        {
            List<abc> list = new List<abc>() ;
        }
    }
```

I want to add all the fields which i used in my class in a list and display them by using a list.. plzz tell.. how can i write a code in c# ??

Comment: Can you edit the question and add an example of what the output should be?

Comment: You might want to have a look at PropertyGrid (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.aspx)

Comment: Please read at-least a minimum level of  Object Oriented Program or try to understand what is OOP's and then start work. Its worthless to ask syntax and logic. Its waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

Well first create an instance of `abc`

```
abc instance = new abc();
//then set the properties
abc.Property1 = "Some value";
//similarly set the value of rest of the properties.

//insert this instance in your list by using add method
list.Add(instance);

//iterate through each instance in list

foreach(abc instance in list)
{
    //print value of a property
    console.Writeline(abc.Property1);
    //similarly other properties
}
```

Comment: can i use the claas name instead of the intance?? how can i print all the property value in a single console statement??

Comment: `can i use the claas name instead of the intance??` for what exactly? `how can i print all the property value in a single console statement??` console.Writeline(abc.Property1 + abc.Property2); similarly you can add rest of the properties

Comment: can we declare our list like this:

list<classname> list= new list<classname>();

so that we can use all the class properties as objects in the list??

Comment: Yes we can. You have done it right in your example `List<abc> list = new List<abc>() ;` here abc is class name

Comment: Nope. I think these hints are enough for a beginner. You should do rest of the effort

Comment: can u plzz tell me the syntax for writing the list??

Comment: List<className> listName = new List<ClassName>();

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print out all properties of objects, then you might want to use reflection code, e.g:

```
public class abc
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

    //....

var list = new List<abc>();
list.Add(new abc() {Name="instance 1"});
list.Add(new abc() {Name="instance 2"});

foreach (var instance in list)
{
    foreach (var property in instance.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(property.Name + "=" +
                          property.GetValue(instance, null));
    }
}
```

Comment: where did u declare the main method?? it wont compile...plz help me with the proper code..